# Having issue while implementing custom gitlab hook

Tags: git, github, hook, gitlab, githooks

I am implementing a custom gitlab hook. While some one pushes in master, I want to update a specific file. Then commit this change and push it to remote origin. The hook looks like below:

```
clone_repo(){
     //cloning a specifc branch on my_app dir 
      export GIT_WORK_TREE="path/my_app"
    }
cd_app(){
    cd my_app
}
update_file(){
  // updating random.java
}
commit_file(){
    git commit -m "commit from hook" random.java
}


while read oldrev newrev refname
do
 if [ ${refname} = "refs/heads/master" ]
 then
     clone_repo
     cd_app && update_file
     commit_file && push_it
     exit 0
 fi
done
```

The hook is running but `cd_app && update_file` is not doing what is suppose to do (not updating update_file). I assuming `cd_app` is not changing the dir (via shell print).

But for testing when I set `refname="refs/heads/master"` just before the `if` checking, it works fine!

Could not find where gitlab logs for custom_hooks. And it seems I am missing something. Can you guys give me further reference or identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it for my system.

First, GIT_WORK_TREE look like the this:

```sh
$ # GIT_WORK_TREE 
$ pwd
/home/git/loging_at_post_receive
$ 
$ git remote -v
origin  /home/git/repositories/gitlab-user/loging_at_post_receive.git/ (fetch)
origin  /home/git/repositories/gitlab-user/loging_at_post_receive.git/ (push)
$ 
$ ls
log.txt
$ 
$ git log --oneline
5aecefe first commit
```

Next, hook script is as follows:

```sh
$ # BARE repository
$ pwd
/home/git/repositories/gitlab-user/test_hook.git
$ 
$ cat hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/bash
clone_repo(){
    #cloning a specifc branch on my_app dir 
    export GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/git/loging_at_post_receive"
}
cd_app(){
    cd /home/git/loging_at_post_receive
}
update_file(){
    date >> log.txt
    echo "update_file"
}
commit_file(){
    git --git-dir=.git add log.txt
    git --git-dir=.git commit -m "commit from hook"
    echo "commit_file"
}
push_it(){
    git --git-dir=.git push origin master
    echo "push_it"
}
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
 if [ ${refname} = "refs/heads/master" ]
 then
     clone_repo
     cd_app && update_file
     commit_file && push_it
     exit 0
 fi
done
```

Then, git push from PC to GitLab. (please pay attention to "remote:" area)

```sh
$ # on PC
$ echo 1 >> README
$ git commit -am 'test'
$ git push origin master
[master 9aed67e] test
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 239 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: update_file
remote: [master 0ce599e] commit from hook
remote:  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
remote: commit_file
remote: To /home/git/repositories/gitlab-user/loging_at_post_receive.git/
remote:    5aecefe..0ce599e  master -> master
remote: push_it
To https://gitlab-server/gitlab-user/test_hook.git
   712a3d1..9aed67e  master -> master
```

As a result

```sh
$ # GIT_WORK_TREE 
$ pwd
/home/git/loging_at_post_receive
$ 
$ git log --oneline
0ce599e commit from hook
5aecefe first commit
$ 
$ git log origin/master --oneline
0ce599e commit from hook
5aecefe first commit
```